# Laravel 7 Set Min. age for user

Tags: laravel, validation

I need help to set a minimum age for the user to be over 18 years.

This is the user's controller

```
   $request->validate([
            'first_name'              => 'required|max:255',
            'last_name'              => 'required|max:255',
            'status'              => 'required|max:50',
            'phone'              => 'required','unique:users','min:10','numeric',
            'date_of_birth'             =>'required|date',
            'address'            => 'required|max:255',
            'country'              => 'required',
            'role_id'              => 'required|max:11',
            'email'              =>[
                'required',
                'email',
                'max:255',
                Rule::unique('users')->ignore($row->id)
            ],
```

**profile blade**

```
 <div class="form-group">
                <label>{{__("Date Of Birth")}}</label>
                <input type="text" value="{{ old('date_of_birth',$dataUser->date_of_birth? display_date($dataUser->date_of_birth) :'') }}" name="date_of_birth" placeholder="{{__("Date Of Birth")}}" class="form-control date-picker">
                <i class="fa fa-birthday-cake input-icon"></i>
            </div>
```

Comment: Absolutely nothing here to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.  Please refrain from tag-spam.  Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dates in date `:before` and `:after` validators are be passed into the [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function, so you can do this like that:

`'date_of_birth' => 'required|date|before:18 years ago',`

Read more here : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-before

Comment: @Tania You can write some words about how `before` rule works with `strtotime()` here. That's will be helpful for future readers.

Comment: @ Eklavya  I have changed to  `'birthday' => [ 'required', 'date',       'before:'.Carbon::now()->subYears(18),

            ],`   with  `use Carbon\Carbon;`